# HTML/ Javascript : URL Redirect from Selected field

Tags: javascript, html

The below select box works absolutely fine. It redirects depending on the selected option.

```
<select name="redirect" onChange="window.document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" value="GO">
   <option selected="selected">Select One</option>
   <option value="http://www.google.com">Google</option>
   <option value="http://www.gmail.com">Gmail</option>
 </select>
```

But I have a complex dropdown box like this:

```
<select name="menu" onChange="window.document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" value="GO">
    <option value="">Select Project</option>
    <option value="http://www.google.com">Type 1</option>
    <option value="Type 2">Type 2</option>
    <option value="Type 3">Type 3</option>
</select>
```

I know the above select box makes no sense as i am using onChange to redirect and using type 2 & type 3 as options.

**Question:** When I select the Type 1 it should redirect to google else if type 2 or type 3 are selected, its values should be submitted to my form.

How can we achieve this. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try something like this:

```
<select name="menu" onChange="javascript: if (this.value == 'http://www.google.com'){window.document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;}else{document.forms['myform'].submit();} " value="GO">
<option value="">Select Project</option>
<option value="http://www.google.com">Type 1</option>
<option value="Type 2">Type 2</option>
<option value="Type 3">Type 3</option>
</select>
```

PS: Here: document.forms['myform'].submit();....you change myForm with your form name-id ;)

Saludos

Comment: In else part of your onChange, instead of sending an alert i need to just store the values in the select tag.

I do not want to send any alerts I either redirect if its value google or store the rest.

Comment: I put the alerts at a mode of example....instead of the alert you can put the code you need ;)....i think you can be able to undestand...sorry....im gonna edit the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

html is like this as you want:

```
<form name="fm_memu">
    <input type="text" name="ipt_menu" value=""/>
</form>
<select name="menu" onChange="if(this.selectedIndex){if(this.selectedIndex < 2){window.document.location.href=this.value;}else{window.document.forms['fm_memu']['ipt_menu'].value=this.value;}}" value="GO">
    <option value="">Select Project</option>
    <option value="http://www.google.com">Type 1</option>
    <option value="Type 2">Type 2</option>
    <option value="Type 3">Type 3</option>
</select>
```